Why async await compiles with Swift 4.2
I have an iOS project with some async await functions. I update Swift Language Version setting in Xcode Build Settings to 4.2 and the project still able to compile. How Swift 4.2 knows how to compile async await functions, since they was implemented in Swift 5.5?
I use Xcode 16

Here's the answer from the official Apple support to a similar question: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/750383.

Your project compiles with async/await despite setting Swift Language Version to 4.2 because Xcode 16 uses the latest Swift compiler (Swift 5.5+) under the hood. The Swift Language Version setting only limits language features but doesn’t disable newer runtime capabilities.
To ensure consistency, update the Swift Language Version to 5.5 or later in Build Settings to align with the concurrency features you’re using.
